# Angular Material $mdToast throws error in Firebug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I basically copied the code from https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast
and wanted to use the "simpleToast" for first testing.
I keep getting "Error: $mdToast.showSimple is not a function" in firebug. Do I need to install that somehow??
Google didn't gave me any results for other people having this problem so I start to have the feeling that I did something elementary completely wrong.

$mdToast is included in my parameter list of my controller function and ng-material is included and works fine (except this toast thing).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: No, I cannot unfortunately... it's too complex everything is in various files :( Do you have any idea what might cause this error? Is it normally enough to just include $mdtoast in the controller parameter list?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot post the code, Here is the sample [`MdToast`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/kjhyL3ze/) which is made with material Design.

**Code:**

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $mdToast) {
    $scope.message = "Hello World";        
    $scope.showToast = function() {
        var toast = $mdToast.simple()
          .content('Hello world')
          .action('OK')
          .highlightAction(false)
          .position('left top right');
      $mdToast.show(toast);
    };
});
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/i3cr79E.jpg Sorry for the blurring, I just don't want my colleagues to find that here :p

Comment: and your sample is not working, it throws the same error in firebug. the function is not found... I have of course included ngMaterial in my controller

Comment: yes, I'm sure that this code works.. the mistake is somehow created on my side... it doesn't work in chrome either! what do you mean by "check the material version"?
angular
.module('...',[
 'ui.router',
 'ngMaterial',
 'nvd3',
 'duScroll'
])

Comment: i have added some references in External Resources section, try to add them as reference in your code and check

Comment: which reference should I add exactly and where is the External Ressource section?

Comment: shall we continue in chat?

Comment: probably if teamviewer or something, i can help you

Comment: You need some repuration for that, ok check this image and add the references http://oi66.tinypic.com/2ntxuog.jpg

Comment: I have all these files included... I keep getting the same error and everything else works. Just $mdToast does not, and I have no idea why

Comment: unless you post your code, or create plunker/jsfiddle nothing much i can help